# Dalvik format failed with error 1 on ServerAssistant

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dalvik

I Found this Error `"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"` While I Compile `ServerAssistant` On `Eclipse`
This is the download link to my modifications project
"http://www.4shared.com/file/fXNDNs5A/ServerAssistant.html"

I have tried cleaning the project and looking at all the other solution to the problem on this website. Has someone also found some obscure solution to this error?

Comment: What is serverAssistant how would we come to know?

Answer (score 0):

this error you got because the library which you have added in the project it was conflict with another class or library, may be the another library or class which was already added into the project. check the complete error and library which you have added into the project